# RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey does not work with IPv6

Tags: c#, registry, ipv6

I'm using:

```
var rk = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "IPv6MachineAddress");
```

and getting "The network path was not found" error.

The remote machine exists. Also I'm able to modify registry using WMI via IPv6.

Does anybody know what is wrong with OpenRemoteBaseKey?

Thanks in advance
Vasyl

Answer (score 1):

"IPv6MachineAddress" seems like an incredibly unusual name for a machine.  Be sure to specify the *machine* name, not the registry key name.

Comment: "Be sure to specify the *machine name*, not the IP address." =)

Comment: Instead of "IPv6MachineAddress" should be host, ipv4 address or ipv6 address, it works with host and ipv4, but not with ip6...

Comment: Ask this at serverfault.com.  Do make sure you ask the question better, they won't understand "IPv6MachineAddress" either.

Comment: @vasyl: I tried this on two machines, both running the remote registry service. It failed to connect using either ipv4 or ipv6 addresses, but it succeeded when specifying the maching name.